# Where should I put upload function in Vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, coding-style, refactoring

I have an `ImageUploader` component through which I upload pictures in my project.

Currently, it is necessary to use different endpoints for uploading, and I want to refactor this component.

I see two ways:

1. I can move upload method to the parent component using `this.$emit(onUpload, files)`, and in the parent component: `<ImageUploader @onUpload='uploadHandler'/>`
2. Pass action as prop in the component that will be used for loading
   `<ImageUploader :uploadAction="AProjectMedia.UPLOAD_IMAGE" />`, and in the component, use it like this: `this.$store.dispatch(uploadAction, files)`

How correct are my options? and what options are there still?

Answer (score 1):

I would say number 1 is better. According to best practices, communication between components happens in two ways:

`Parent -> Child` via **props**;

`Child -> Parent` via **events**;

For more info, see [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-components-interact-in-vue-and-what-is-vuex). Even when I'm using Vuex, I prefer this communication pattern instead of call actions/getters from child component.

Answer (score 1):

Number one seems better since it keeps your component clean for a single purpose (uploading the file). Any side effect should probably be handled by the parent. This way, the parent components (which are different) bear the responsibility for the different functions.

Another option is to call the action directly from the child component, though this could be an issue if you're aiming for reusability.